# Как сделать релиз в mingw32?

Tags: windows, g++, mingw

Как сделать release-сборку (gcc g++ и т.д.) программы с mingw32 в windows?

Comment: Объясните нормально, что такое "release-сборка". Какую программу хотите собрать ?

Обычно для сборки программ делают Makefile. В MinGW/bin есть команда make.
Обычно это mingw32-make.exe, но я пререименовываю ее просто в make.

Comment: make файл у меня есть, всё компилится и запускается, но не работает на другой машине, т.к. что-то не хватает. Ту же программу делаю release в code::blocks с mingw - на другой машине всё работает. Вот я хочу узнать какие флаги компилятора нужны для release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никаких параметров gcc для релиз сборки не нужно.
Если нужно отладить, то `gcc -g`

Если проект содержит несколько файлов, то нужен файл `Makefile`

Answer (score 0):

С скомпилированных exe прилагайте MinGW дистрибутив. Он установит недостающие либы. Либо, если есть желание экспериментировать, посмотрите, каких dll не хватает и положите рядом.

Comment: Посмотреть каких же библиотек не хватает можно с помощью программы Dependency Viewer, которая бывает как в составе сред программирования от MS, так и в виде отдельно скачиваемой программы.